# How to merge 2 arrays columns of a DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've come up with this udf

```
def merge[A: TypeTag] =
  udf { (a: Seq[A], b: Seq[A]) =>
    if (b == null) a else a ++ b
  }
```

Is there a way to avoid using an udf (for performance reason) ?

Comment: UDFs are avoided because they can not be optimized by Spark. But in your case it'll be cleaner and perhaps more efficient too.